# How do you make sure that both signals are powered?

Tags: minecraft-redstone

So, I'm making a "map" to try to impress my friends with my redstone and commands, and I wanna make a voting system for a bedwars game. So, I want to make it so that two people have to agree on one mode to prevent complete chaos(there's gonna be three people including me), and I want to make it so that once those two players step on certain pressure plates, it will run a command. If one player steps on a pressure plate of a certain mode, it's not chosen. If no one steps on the pressure plates, the mode isn't chosen either.

Comment: AND gate. Or golden pressure plate, 2 redstone dust and repeater after these, for handling this with a single pressure plate instead of 2.

Comment: As in, there are two pressure plates and both need to be activated to run a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an AND gates.

How it works is that you have 3 levers/inputs all leading up into 3 blocks with redstone torches. Then there will be redstone running into your command block. Im not able to take screenshots right now but will edit the post asap.

Comment: thanks for the info about the AND gate, saying it on text is kinda confusing, but I've managed to go to the minecraft wiki and find my answer there.